# How to upgrade the centos 5.8 to centos 6X?

Tags: centos, centos6, centos5

I am using centos 5.8 in xencenter , i need to upgrade  to centos6.5.

i tried with yum update it will updated to centos 5.10 only,please any one help me.

Thanks,

Prasad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that you are trying to update a virtual machine.  If this is the case then you can try the following.

1. Boot your CentOS 5.8 VM using the CentOS6 ISO
2. On the initial screen press tab
3. when the boot command appears, append upgradeany

   **vmlinuz initrd=initrd.img upgradeany**

When you pass the language and devices selections and the system is done examining the storage, you will be prompted if you want to upgrade an existing installation and be shown a drop down list of versions that were found.

Comment: Thanks Alex, But the vm(citrix xen center)will be in remote location. today i will try and let me know .